# Using sed to index files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Does sed contain a feature which can be used to index files? What I mean is, if you have a file with a list of indexes, then is it possible to use that index list to extract lines from another file with the specific index?

For example, the index file:

```
5C
120D
1M
```

The other file could be a sequence, thus is sed able to read through the sequence and print the lines which contain the index above?

i.e. a sequence with "C" in position 5 and a second sequence with "D" in position 120.

Thus the sequence file may look something like this (with many more lines and longer sequences)

```
AHOPLIKKJL...
ZIXOPAOSLA...
QYRHCKDIOS...
MKIAOOPSLB
```

In this case lines 3 and 4 would be printed (since the index above shows 5C and 1M), giving:

```
QYRHCKDIOS...
MKIAOOPSLB...
```

I have tried a few things but can't really get the desired output:

```
sed 's/.\{20\}\(.\).*/\1/;q'

grep -f index_file sequence_file   # also tried with grep
```

Has anyone got any ideas? Please bear in mind the length of each sequence extends in hundreds of characters and there are thousands of rows. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO `awk` will be more suitable for this job.

Comment: Why does `grep` not work?